# how to split listview by parts in android

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview, I want to split that listview manually by showing 10 times for each page. I have a listview of 80 to 85 items.My problems is I have to split that listview by 8 to 9 parts by showing 10-10 itmes for each page. Simply its like a pagination manually I have to show it. Is it possible? I am unable to clear the list, and I am using custom adapter extending baseadater.

Answer (score 0):

I think u can use viewpager, add dynamically pages to viewpager with specific number of list items
see this example of viewpager

http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/view-pager-example-in-android-development/

Comment: Sorry it's not useful for me. I don't know the exact size of the list.It may varies.How can I do with viewpager?

Comment: You need to create pages when u get new data,you dont need fixed no of pages

Answer (score 0):

For exmaple, for [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) you can add new values with [addAll](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#addAll%28T...%29) and update it with [notifyDataSetChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29).

Comment: I will get the list in a single response. I have to show them when user click on next button.I used notifydataSetChanged but previous items added to list.And able to clear the list.I didn't find any method to clear the list.There is no customAdater.clear() method also.What can I do?

Comment: Then you should implement clear method yourself like in ArrayAdapter.